# abrir ejecutable con sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Estoy intentando abrir un archivo ejecutable hecho con python mediante un script de sql mediante el siguiente codigo:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

use master
go
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [dominio\usuario]
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'dominio\usuario', 'password'
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [dominio\usuario]


Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\test.exe'
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar el proceso en sql me devuelve "Acceso denegado"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el usuario tiene permisos de administrador en el equipo, pero he intentado ejecutar varios programas y hasta archivos txt y no he podido.

A que se debe y como solucionar este error?

Actualización:
cambie el archivo de ubicación a C:\carpeta_test y el error de Acceso denegado ya no aparece, el script sql no lanza error, sin embargo el .exe sigue sin ejecutarse.

Comment: "El usuario tiene permisos de administrador" == cuál usuario? Según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) del comando, _The Windows process spawned by xp_cmdshell has the same security rights as the SQL Server service account_. Entonces, estás seguro que le estás asignando permisos sobre los archivos al usuario correcto? Lo otro, no ejecutes cosas en Users, que las carpetas de usuario suelen ser las que más restricciones tienen. Usa algo en C:\Workspace o algo así

Comment: Me parece que tienes una confusión, el `xp_cmdshell` es para ejecutar un comando en el Servidor No en tu equipo o en el del usuario. Lo digo por que `C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\test.exe` no pareciera ser un path válido para el servidor.

Comment: disulpen la confusión, estoy ejecutando sql directamente desde el servidor, el "usuario" que indico en el script es  un usuario con permisos de administrador en el servidor

Comment: @Alfabravo como dijiste, cambie el archivo de ubicación y agregre directamente a 'C:\carpeta_test' y efectivamente ya no aparece el error de "Acceso denegado", sin embargo sigue sin ejecutar el archivo

Comment: Por qué estás seguro que no se ejecuta? Cuál es el resultado esperado de la ejecución? Recuerda que todos los procesos hijos de ese cmdshell se van a ejecutar a nombre del service account.

Comment: La forma más sencilla de verificar un `xp_cmdshell`  es correr cualquier comando básico de DOS, por ejemplo: `xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\'`, verifica que esto funcione en primer lugar, si lo hace seguramente el problema lo tienes en `test.exe` y no en `xp_cmdshell`

Comment: Por que no se esta actualizando la base de datos, el script debiese iniciar un ejecutable desarrollado en python que extrae información desde distintas paginas web y las sube a una base de datos alojada en el servidor. el proceso funciona bien cuando ejecuto el archivo .exe desde el CMD, pero no cuando corro el sql

Comment: René, el error "Acceso denegado" puede darse por que no tienes acceso a una ruta, ¿existe en el servidor la carpeta `C:\Users\usuario\Desktop`?